# WCF: with and without, aspNetCompatibilityEnabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have two WCF services in my application that are using for ajax calls.

First one is using `HttpContext.Current.Session` so I have to set

aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "true"

in my Web.config.

Second one is used to show progress values so it has to be called during code behind executions but when I have `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "true"`, it wait for other things to complete and then start my service.
so I have to set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "false"

How can I set `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "true"` for first one AND 
`aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "false"` for second one?

UPDATE-------------

what I want is to have two WCF services.
 First one:
 With `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "true"` 
Second:
 With `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "false"`

Comment: What are those "other things"?

Comment: What? I don't understand you. What do you want?

Comment: Other things: I mean other processec in current session such as generating reports

Comment: what I want is to have two WCF services
First one: With aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "true"
Second:  With aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = "false"

Answer (score 2):

From the doc: [*ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for the current AppDomain*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.aspnetcompatibilityenabled(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can't have a different setting per endpoint because the setting is for the complete app domain your app is running in. So either all your endpoints or none of your endpoints (either WCF or other handlers) run in ASP.NET compatibility mode. And with that thel have access to features from the HTTP application pipeline or none have access to those features.

If you really need to distinguish between the two, you have to split your endpoints over two applications, each running in its own app domain/ application pool.

Comment: I know it, but it was easily possible using asmx WebServices using function attributes.I think I have to go back using them.!